# Attaching Output console (cmd.exe) to vb6 Textbox or panal

Tags: vb.net, vb6

How Attaching Output console (cmd.exe) to vb6 Textbox or panal:
I am trying to follow steps:

- click on button (which will run batch file)
  so, i want to show the output of the batch file in vb6 text box or i want to show the console output On VB6 panel.

so, can anyone help me for this?

I have used following simple code:

```
Private Sub Command11_Click(Index As Integer)
Dim sPathUser As String
sPathUser = Environ$("EENV")
Shell sPathUser & "\Xyz.bat"
End Sub
```

so, i just want to display 'Xyz.bat' console output on dialouge box or on text editor or simple editor?

Answer (score 0):

I give you my working example, you use `process` class using `Async` events so you get the output data and errors aswell.

```
 Dim Proceso As New Process

 'Register Output async event
 AddHandler Proceso.OutputDataReceived, AddressOf CallbackProcesoAsync
 'Register error output async event
 AddHandler Proceso.ErrorDataReceived, AddressOf ErrorDataReceivedAsync

 Dim startInfo As New ProcessStartInfo
 startInfo.FileName = execFile
 startInfo.Arguments = CmdExeArguments
 startInfo.ErrorDialog = False
 startInfo.UseShellExecute = False

 Private Sub CallbackProcesoAsync(sender As Object, args As System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventArgs)

        If Not args.Data Is Nothing AndAlso Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(args.Data) Then
            'Do stuff with your output results    
        End If
 End Sub



  Private Sub CallbackProcesoAsync(sender As Object, args As System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventArgs)

        If Not args.Data Is Nothing AndAlso Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(args.Data) Then
         'Do stuff with error output

        End If
  End Sub
```

Comment: Isnt there is any small command which can simply shows the the console on VB6 page (panal)?   ==> like we can display excel sheet on dialogue